# C# Libraries Node Edge Graphs

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, graph, physics-engine

I want to write a program that produces force directed node-edge graphs similar to [this video](http://youtu.be/Onbn285lris). What are some good C# libraries that will let me do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just looking for a .Net graph library, try QuickGraph http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/. It is a generic graph library with many algorithms implemented, and easy for unit test.

Comment: I took a look at quickgraph and it looks like it has everything I want in terms of a graph data structure, but how do I create the graphic itself?

Comment: In reference to QuickGraph, as you may find out, Codeplex is shutting down. Here is the link to [Brian Harry's Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/03/31/shutting-down-codeplex/) for more information regrading archive and migration information.

Answer (score 1):

Graph# uses QuickGraph to render Node Graph: http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/
I've found it quite useful.